# How to calculate the integral $I\left(a,b,c\right)=\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\times\mbox{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}\right)du$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to compute the following integral depending on a,b and c all strictly positive real numbers:
$$I\left(a,b,c\right)=\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\times\mbox{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}\right)du$$

I tend to use the 'Brute force' solution that is to rely on the integral series of $exp(x)$ and $erfi(x)$. This gives this development:
$$I\left(a,b,c\right)=\int_{a}^{b}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(u^{2k}\right)}{k!}\times\mbox{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}\right)du$$
$$\Leftrightarrow I\left(a,b,c\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\int_{a}^{b}u^{2k}\times\mbox{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}\right)du$$
As:$$\mbox{erfi}\left(x\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{2j+1}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}$$
this gives:
$$I\left(a,b,c\right)=\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\int_{a}^{b}u^{2k}\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{u}{c}^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}du$$
$$\Leftrightarrow I\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}c^{-\frac{2j+1}{2}}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{u^{\frac{4k+2j+1}{2}}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}du$$
The inner integral evaluates like:
$$\int_{a}^{b}u^{\frac{4k+2j+1}{2}}du=\left[\frac{u^{\frac{4k+2j+3}{2}}}{\frac{4k+2j+3}{2}}\right]_{a}^{b}$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\int_{a}^{b}u^{\frac{4k+2j+1}{2}}du=\frac{2}{4k+2j+3}\left[b^{\frac{4k+2j+3}{2}}-a^{\frac{4k+2j+3}{2}}\right]$$
This leads to:
$$I\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{2c^{-\frac{2j+1}{2}}}{(4k+2j+3)\left(2j+1\right)j!}\left[b^{\frac{4k+2j+3}{2}}-a^{\frac{4k+2j+3}{2}}\right]$$

I assume this to be right but is there a more elegant solution than this double sum to the infinite ?

EDIT: i correct the question to state that a and b are **strictly** positive real numbers, and also the missing term in the final result.

Comment: Have a look at my edit.

Answer (score 2):

*I apologize for serious mistakes in my previous edit.*

I think that it could be better to avoid expanding $e^{u^2}$ and then to face
$$I_n=\int u^{\frac{2n+1}2}\, e^{u^2}\,du=\frac{1}{2} u^{n-\frac{1}{2}} \left(-u^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n}{2}} \Gamma
   \left(\frac{2n+3}{4},-u^2\right)$$

What is interesting is, if $u>0$
$$ u^{n-\frac{1}{2}} \left(-u^2\right)^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n}{2}}=\sin \left( (2 n+1)\frac{\pi}{4} \right)+i\,\cos \left( (2 n+1)\frac{\pi}{4} \right)$$

Then, a single summation but involving a bunch of complex numbers.

**Edit**

Let
$$\alpha_j=\frac{ \sin \left((2j+1)\frac{\pi}{4} \right)+i
   \cos \left((2j+1)\frac{\pi}{4}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi }\,(2 j+1)\, j!\,c^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}}$$ and, to keep the positive value if $b>a$, then
$$I(a,b,c,p)=\sum_{j=0}^p \alpha_j\,\left(\Gamma
   \left(\frac{2j+3}{4},-a^2\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{2j+3}{4},-b^2\right)     \right)$$ which is a real number.  Computing the partial sums for a test example
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & I(2,4,\pi,p) \\
 0 & 1.43839229786\times 10^6 \\
 1 & 2.02874651505\times 10^6 \\
 2 & 2.24708810578\times 10^6 \\
 3 & 2.31125186810\times 10^6 \\
 4 & 2.32666704737\times 10^6 \\
 5 & 2.32978678296\times 10^6 \\
 6 & 2.33033141250\times 10^6 \\
 7 & 2.33041495543\times 10^6 \\
 8 & 2.33042638058\times 10^6 \\
 9 & 2.33042779000\times 10^6 \\
 10 &2.33042794834\times 10^6 \\
 11 & 2.33042796467\times 10^6 \\
 12 & 2.33042796623\times 10^6 \\
 13 & 2.33042796637\times 10^6 \\
 14 & 2.33042796638\times 10^6
\end{array}
\right)$$ Using $p=100$, the difference
$$I(a,b,c,100)-I(a,b,c,\infty)=-7.046\times 10^{-147}$$

**Update**

$$J=\int e^{u^{2}}\,\mbox{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}\right)\,du$$ Let $u=c\,x^2$ to make
$$J=2 c\int x\, e^{c^2 x^4} \text{erfi}(x)\,dx= \frac{4c}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}\int x^{2(j+1)}\, e^{c^2 x^4}\,dx$$
$$K_j=\int x^{2(j+1)}\, e^{c^2 x^4}\,dx=-\frac{1}{4} x^{2 j+3} E_{\frac{1-2j}{4}}\left(-c^2 x^4\right)$$

Comment: a and b are real strictly positive numbers ( i correct the question above to precise that)

Comment: it's me or $$u^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\left(-u^{2}\right)^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n}{2}}=\left(u\right)^{n-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}-n}\left(-1\right)^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n}{2}}=\left(-1\right)^{\frac{1}{4}-\frac{n}{2}}$$

Comment: @BenG73. What do you think about my solution ? The problem is that everything has to be done in the complex domain which is not always funny.

Comment: @BenG73. Isn't the same ?

Comment: yes, you are right :) i will take time this evening to consider your way to another solution

Comment: I agree with your calculus  but this leaves us with two solutions among which one seems to have imaginary terms. if the two coincide, there must be a way to eliminate imaginary terms while the summation to infinite is done, no ?

Comment: In relation to your update 'part', what is exactly the special function you noted E ? Is it the incomplete gamma function ?

Comment: @BenG73. The exponential integral function.

Comment: The Generalized exponential integral function i guess.

Comment: i ordered all our common developments into one definite (i hope) answer below.

Comment: As the power of the Exponential Integrale function above is $\frac{1-2j}{4}$, this means this last value may not be an integer or even may not be positive... Is the Exponential Integral function still defined when n is negative or fractionnal ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's begin by an expansion of the $\mbox{erfi}(x)$
function:

$$I\left(a,b,c\right)=\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\times\mbox{erfi}\left(\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}\right)du$$
$$\Leftrightarrow I\left(a,b,c\right)=\int_{a}^{b}exp\left(u^{2}\right)\times\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}^{2j+1}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}du$$
$$\Leftrightarrow I\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}\int_{a}^{b}e^{u^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{u}{c}}^{2j+1}du$$
$$\Leftrightarrow I\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{c^{-\frac{\left(2j+1\right)}{2}}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}\int_{a}^{b}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du$$
$$\Leftrightarrow I\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{c^{-\frac{\left(2j+1\right)}{2}}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}\int_{a}^{b}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du$$
Then we need to compute the value of the integral $\int_{a}^{b}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du$ .

First let's split the integral in two new ones:
$$\int_{a}^{b}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du=\int_{a}^{+\infty}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du-\int_{b}^{+\infty}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du$$

Let $x=\frac{u^{2}}{a^{2}}$
, then: $u=a\sqrt{x}$ $\Rightarrow dx=\frac{2u}{a^{2}}du=\frac{2\sqrt{x}}{a}du$
so that: $$\int_{a}^{+\infty}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du=\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{a^{2}x}\left(a\sqrt{x}\right)^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}\frac{a}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$
$$=\frac{a^{\frac{2j+3}{2}}}{2}\int_{1}^{+\infty}e^{a^{2}x}x^{\frac{2j-1}{4}}dx$$
This last integral is nothing less than the expression of the Generalized Exponential Integral function $E_{n}\left(y\right)$ such that:
$$E_{n}\left(y\right)=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-yt}}{t^{n}}dt=\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-yt}}{t^{n}}dt$$
with $n=\frac{1-2j}{4}$  and $y=-a^{2}$.
Then, we have:
$$\int_{a}^{b}e^{u^{2}}u^{\frac{2j+1}{2}}du=\frac{a^{\frac{2j+3}{2}}}{2}E_{\frac{1-2j}{4}}\left(-a^{2}\right)-\frac{b^{\frac{2j+3}{2}}}{2}E_{\frac{1-2j}{4}}\left(-b^{2}\right)$$
so that in the end, we have:
$$I\left(a,b,c\right)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{c^{-\frac{\left(2j+1\right)}{2}}}{\left(2j+1\right)j!}\left(\frac{a^{\frac{2j+3}{2}}}{2}E_{\frac{1-2j}{4}}\left(-a^{2}\right)-\frac{b^{\frac{2j+3}{2}}}{2}E_{\frac{1-2j}{4}}\left(-b^{2}\right)\right)$$
Note that this last result may also be expressed in terms of incomplete Gamma function as $$E_{n}\left(y\right)=y^{n-1}\Gamma\left(1-n,y\right)$$.

Comment: EDIT: i still wonder if the term $\frac{1-2j}{4}$ is not an issue for the Exponential Integral function...